# How to detect dot (.) at the start of a line in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove a dot (`.`) if appears at the start of the line, so for example:

```
hi,
<new line> .
<new line> How are you.
```

How can I remove this line?

Comment: That's three different questions. "how can I remove this line", is not the same question as "How to detect dot" or "I want to remove dot". Which one do you want answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove a dot at the start of a line:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^\.", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Remove an entire line if it starts with a dot:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^\..*\r\n", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Remove an entire line if it contains only a dot:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^\.\r\n", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Remove an entire line if it starts with a dot and possibly contains trailing whitespace:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^\.[^\r\n\S]*\r\n", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = "hi,\n.\nHow are you.".Replace("\n.\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use built-in [string-comparisons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) - there  are plenty avialable.

You could use [RegEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

But it all comes to one point --> what have you tried? and [please read the docs](http://www.readthefuckingmanual.com/).

Short possible answer:

```
// allLines is your List/Array/Enumerable of all lines that need checking
foreach(string line in allLines){
    if(!line.Trim().StartsWith("."){
        // Do whatever you like with the found string.
        line = line.Remove(".",1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does "detect" mean in your case? If it's just to return true/false if a dot occurs, you can just search for `"\n."` - a line break followed by a dot. You don't even need regex for it:

```
bool weHaveDot = myString[0] == "." || (myString.IndexOf("\n.") > -1);
```

Comment: That's true. Easily tweaked, though.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
MyLine.Substring(MyLine.IndexOf("<new line> ") + 11).StartsWith(".")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the answer depends on what the question means.

My guess is that you have several lines, and you want to remove those lines that consist of only a dot. Right?

Then the solution would be:

- Split the string into a string array, each of which contains one line
- Remove all array elements that consist of just a dot
- Join the string array back together.

And you don't need a regex for that. (Unless you want to get some experience in regexes; in that case, sorry.)